# How can I format my Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, format

I want to format my Ubuntu and make it as no one used my computer before. Please do not tell me about Disks then format only a portion. Actually I want to format everything and start over again. Please help

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in Ubuntu installation to Erase the whole disk and full install Ubuntu. Then all the files and partitions will be erased.

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu installation]

Answer (score 0):

If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD (don't use a USB flash drive please) in `Try Ubuntu` mode, you can run `gparted` to lay down a new MBR or GPT partition table on the drive, effectively wiping out the drive. Use GPT if you have a newer computer that is UEFI, or have disks larger than 2TB.

Then quit gparted, and just double-click the `Install Ubuntu` icon on the desktop to start the installation.

Comment: boot into live cd and open a terminal. sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4k. this overwrites your whole disk with zeroes. it DELETES everything on disk sda. be CAREFULL.